# changing the spacing between tick labels on Matplotlib Heatmap

Tags: matplotlib, heatmap, axis-labels, yaxis

I am using the following code to generate this [heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC9sY.png):

```
h= np.vstack((aug2014, sep2014,oct2014, nov2014, dec2014, jan2015, feb2015, mar2015, apr2015, may2015, jun2015, jul2015, aug2015))

dim = np.arange(1, 32, 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,3))
heatmap = ax.imshow(h, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('Blues', 4), aspect=0.5, clim=[1,144])
cbar = fig.colorbar(heatmap, ticks = [1, 36, 72, 108, 144], label =  'Number of valid records per day')
ax.set_xlabel("Days", fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel("Months", fontsize=15)
ax.set_title("Number of valid records per day", fontsize=20)
ax.set_xticks(range(0,31))
ax.set_xticklabels(dim, rotation=45, ha='center', minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(range(0,13,1))
ax.set_yticklabels(ylabel[7:20])
ax.grid(which = 'minor', color = 'w')
ax.set_facecolor('gray')
fig.show()
```

As you can see, the labels on the y-axis are not very readable. I was wondering whether there would be a way for me to either increase the dimension of the grid cell or change the scale on the axis to increase the space between the labels. I have tried changing the figsize but all it did was to make the colorbar much bigger than the heatmap. I also have have two subsidiary questions:

1. Can someone explain to me why the grid lines do not show on the figure although I have defined them?
2. How can I increase the font of the colorbar title?

Any help would be welcomed!

Comment: First of all, the aspect ratio is set to 0.5, but is this intentional? This is packing the y-axis spacing. If you don't set the aspect ratio, the height of the color bar will be aligned. Also, the grid lines are major, which can be solved by setting the parameter to `which='major'`. For the font size of the color bar, add the following code; the label name in `fig.colorbar()` is not set because it is duplicated. `cbar.set_label('Number of valid records per day', fontsize=14)`

Comment: You can use `from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator; ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(.5)); ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(.5))` to set minor ticks at the halves, which would enable the white grid lines. [matplotlib ticker docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/major_minor_demo.html)

Comment: thanks to both of you I was able to get the figure I wanted! Thank you! :)